# Form Submit Not Working - html, css and javascript, can't get form to hide either

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a form and two things are not working. The form doesn't submit and I can't get it to hide either. I'm trying to make it so if the user clicks on the binocular icon it displays the form and it's hidden until the user does so. I'm a UX Designer trying to up my front-end skills.

HTML:

```
<body>
<a href onclick="document.getElementById('hide').style.display='block'">
    <img src="iconmonstr-binoculars-8.png" width="40" height="30" alt=""/>
    </a><br>
    <p id="demo" style="display:none">
<div class="container">
    <h2>Have a Product Suggestion?</h2>
    <form class="form" id="form">
        <div class="form-control">
          <label for="fName">Full Name</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="Fname" placeholder="Lisa Simpson" />
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i><br>
            <small>Error Message</small><br>
        </div>
      <div class="form-control">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label><br>
        <input type="email" placeholder="iheartthesax@gmail.com" id="email" />
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i><br>
            <small>Error Message</small><br>
        </div>
      <div class="form-control">
        <label for="productDes">Product Description</label><br>
        <textarea name="message" rows="4" cols="35" id="productDes">Describe the product you are looking for, please be as detailed as possible. 
        </textarea>             
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i><br>
            <small>Error Message</small><br>
        </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
    </form>
    </div></p>
```

Javascript:

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const fname = document.getElementById('fname');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const productDes = document.getElementById('productDes');

form.addEventListener('Submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() { 
  //get the values from the inputs
  const fnameValue = fname.value.trim();
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const productDesValue = productDes.value.trim();

  if(fnameValue === '' ) { 
    setErrorFor(fname, 'Oh no! Please add your name.');
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(fname);
  }

if(emailValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Email cannot be blank');
    } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Not a valid email');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(email);
    } 
  if(productDesValue === '' ) { 
    setErrorFor(productDes, 'Oh no! Please add details for the product.');
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(productDes);
  }  
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  const small = formControl.queryselector('small');
  small.innerText = message;
 formControl.className = 'form-control error';
  
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  formControl.className = 'form-control sucess';
    
}
    
function isEmail(email) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}   
  

document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "block";
'''
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://cfnpidifppmenkapgihekkeednfoenal/content/syncpromise.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Answer (score 0):

So for the hiding with `document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "block"` and `document.getElementById('hide').style.display='block'` you are trying to change the display value of something with the id `hide`. I see no such element in your HTML.

I think what you actually want to do is make the Element wit the ID `demo` visible again right? So for the hiding I guess using `document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block"` would fix your problem.

And for the submitting, I am not sure but the events might be case sensitive, have you tried registering to the `submit` event instead of `Submit`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace submit event handler with this code. It will submit the form.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  checkInputs();
});
```